# UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID") equivalent on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

On Windows Phone 7 you can do like this to get an anonymous unique id for the current user.

```
UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID")
```

I have search for a while to find an equivalent for my current Windows 8 (WinRT), but I can't seem to find it. All the results I find, talks about how to get a Hardware/device specific ID, which IS supported, it's just not what I need.

Thanks in advance,
Mads

Comment: Not supported in the current sdk for w8.You have to generate one using hardware/device info.

Comment: Damm, but thanks anyway. I kind of expected this, as I wasn't able to find anything but still...it sucks. Generating it from the hardware/device info is not really what I need, but guess I have to :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out, thanks to xamlgeek an others, that it's not possible to get a Unique User Id in Windows 8 - at least for now.

So I have to fallback on Device Id, which is far from what I needed, but found this code snippet with works perfect (C#):

http://bartwullems.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/windows-8-uniquely-identifying-device.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not good at all, because the user can upgrade his PC config (by pluging a bluetooth adapter or anything else). The good answer is to use the object :

`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["HighPriority"]`

It's synchronized through the different installation of the apps on the cloud, more infos here : 
The HighPriority key is special because it's get automatically during the new installation of the app.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/07/17/roaming-your-app-data.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's unwise to use GetPackageSpecificToken. This ID will change even if user just plug USB device into his PC/tab, or turn Wifi on/off. Actually it's a quite unstable thing, no idea why MSFT has ever made it.

I use LiveConnect instead (only Liveconnect user ID is needed and it's the same on all user devices). It much more reliable. See my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22389679/1656824