# Getting ANID2 in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I used this method in WP8 to get the user property :

```
object userHashId;
UserExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ANID2", out userHashId);
_userId = userHashId.ToString();
```

[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties.trygetvalue.aspx)

But I cannot find these in Windows Phone 8.1. Are there any new API for this
, or any alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it isn't possible under WinRT apps - the link you have provided stays for WP8.1 Silverlight Apps - then I suspect you are trying to develop under WinRT - [API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/br211377.aspx).

You can read more from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4f48d81f-222e-48e0-aa32-fe1fe4880ffe/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-anonymous-identifier-anid-in-a-winrt-application?forum=winappswithcsharp), also [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14779614/2681948) and at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lighthouse/archive/2013/08/27/how-to-identify-unique-device-for-windows-8-and-windows-phone-app.aspx).

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23322202/2681948), maybe the code below will help you:

```
HardwareToken myToken = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
IBuffer hardwareId = myToken.Id;
```

There is also a [Guidance on using the App Specific Hardware ID (ASHWID) to implement per-device app logic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx).